# Action hooks returning old category instead of new category

Tags: categories, actions, terms, email

[With some help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181090/send-an-email-when-custom-post-type-category-is-changed) I created a WP Action to send an email to the author of a post (custom post type) when the category has been changed.

This works ok, except that the function is returning the *previous* category instead of the *current* category.

For example, if the post was **cat2** and the admin updates it to **cat3**, the email gets sent saying that your post has been updated to **cat2** (the category before the update was made).

I'm completely at a loss with this because these hooks ( [`added_term_relationship`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/added_term_relationship/) and [`deleted_term_relationships`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/deleted_term_relationships/) ) are supposed to fire after the category is updated, not before. So how is it possible that they're sending the previous category instead of the updated current category?

My code:

```
function notify_object_terms_updated( $object_id ) {
    $post_id   = get_the_ID();
    $userEmail = types_get_field_meta_value( 'your-email', $post_id );
    $newCat    = get_the_category($post_id);
    $ideaTitle = get_the_title($post_id);
    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";    
    $headers[] = 'From:XYZ Continuous Improvement <email@mydomain.com>';

    static $did = array(); // This function might fire multiple times for the same object, ensure it only runs once
        if ( ! isset( $did[ $object_id ] ) ) {
            $did[ $object_id ] = true;

     wp_mail( 
        $userEmail, 
        'Your Continuous Improvement Idea - ' . $ideaTitle, 
        '<p>The status of your Continuous Improvement idea titled "' . $ideaTitle . '" has been updated to <strong>' . $newCat[0] ->cat_name . '</strong>.</p>' . '<p>You can view the progress of your idea anytime on the <a href="http://continuous.improvemen.com/board">Continuous Improvement Board</a>.</p>',
        $headers 
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'added_term_relationship','notify_object_terms_updated');
add_action( 'deleted_term_relationships','notify_object_terms_updated');
```

edit: declared array.

Comment: A general note, you're adding things to the `$headers` array, but where does the `$headers` array come from? It's never been declared/created? Can you re-indent your code correctly?

Comment: @TomJNowell an array named $headers is created by declaration at lines 7-9.

Comment: It's appended to using the `[]` operator, but it's never actually created, it's only implied

Comment: Are you sure that deleted term relationships is called before added term and not the other way around?

Comment: I've tried it both ways, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Although the hooks are passing you the ID of the changed object in the parameter `$object_id`, you aren't using it and are calling `get_the_ID` instead which will give you the ID of the current loop item.

Try changing your uses of `$post_id` to `$object_id` instead.