# Prevent function from triggering again when post in specific category gets another category?

Tags: categories, actions, email

I have created a function to send out an email to authors when there post is added in the popular category for custom post type.

IT WORKS but there is 1 major issue.  If the post that is **in the popular category gets added to a new category while still in the popular category** it sends off **another email**.

I do under stand why this happens.  It is because a new term relationship was added.  I haven't found a way to handle this and have been trying for a couple days.  So I figured it would best to ask the community here.

Is there a way to prevent this email from sending again?

Here is a simplified version

```
<?php

/**
* Sends out an email when song goes into popular category
*
* @param int $post_id of the song
*/


function emailNotificationSongPopular( $post_id ) {

  if ( has_term( 'popular', 'song_category' ) ) {

    $post    = get_post( $post_id );
    $author  = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
    $terms   = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'song_category' );
    $email   = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_email', true );
    $message = 'Hi ' . $author->display_name;

    wp_mail( $email, "Your song is now in the popular section!", $message );

  }
}
add_action( 'added_term_relationship', 'emailNotificationSongPopular' );
```

Comment: could it also be the case that a song enters the popular category multiple times?

Comment: Well if the song goes in popular category on and off then they will get another email.  But that isn't the case here @Milo .  That could very well be the case if it was automated but these are selected manually by me so I am positive that is not the issue.  This happens when song is already in popular section and gets new category added to it.

Comment: I meant the question only as a consideration for possible solution, not an issue with the code you posted. consider maybe storing whether or not an author has been notified in post meta data, then you don't have to worry about the term issues, you can verify that the meta entry does not exist before sending an email.

Answer (score 2):

We can utilize the `add_term_relationship` action to check if the current post is already assigned as `popular`. `add_term_relationship` fires before a term is inserted.

I also think that you are using the wrong hook here to send your mail on. `added_term_relationship` fires quite early before any error checking. You can still encounter a failure after `added_term_relationship` which means that the term insertion will not happen successfully and will return an error. `set_object_terms` is a better hook to use as it only fires if a term was successfully inserted.

```
/**
 * Fires immediately before an object-term relationship is added.
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 *
 * @param int $object_id Object ID.
 * @param int $tt_id     Term taxonomy ID.
 */
do_action( 'add_term_relationship', $object_id, $tt_id );
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->term_relationships, array( 'object_id' => $object_id, 'term_taxonomy_id' => $tt_id ) );

/**
 * Fires immediately after an object-term relationship is added.
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 *
 * @param int $object_id Object ID.
 * @param int $tt_id     Term taxonomy ID.
 */
do_action( 'added_term_relationship', $object_id, $tt_id );
```

We can try the following (***NOTE:*** This is untested)

```
add_action( 'add_term_relationship', function ( $object_id, $tt_id )
{
    // Check if the post is already in the popular term, if so, bail
    if ( has_term( 'popular', 'song_category', $object_id ) ) 
        return;

    // Check if our post is going to be added as popular, if not, bail 
    if ( 1 !== $tt_id ) // Set the correct ID for popular term
        return;

    /**
     * We are now sure that our post is not yet popular, and we will be 
     * making it popular, so lets continue
     *
     * We will be sending a mail when the term is inserted. We will use the 
     * set_object_terms hook as it fires on successful insertion of the term 
     */
    add_action( 'set_object_terms', function ( $object_id )
    {
        $post    = get_post( $object_id );
        $author  = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
        $terms   = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'song_category' );
        $email   = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_email', true );
        $message = 'Hi ' . $author->display_name;

        wp_mail( $email, "Your song is now in the popular section!", $message );
    });
}, 10, 2 );
```

### EDIT

Make sure that you change `1` in  `1 !== $tt_id` to the exact ID of your term. I have also just copied and pasted your code into my code, so I'm not sure if that is your complete code or if that is working as-is

### EDIT 2

You can use the following if you do not know the ID of the popular term (*I accept that `popular` ids the term slug*)

```
$term_object = get_term_by( 'slug', 'popular', 'song_category' );
$term_id     = $term_object->term_id;
```

Lets rewrite the code to incorporate that

```
add_action( 'add_term_relationship', function ( $object_id, $tt_id )
{
    // Check if the post is already in the popular term, if so, bail
    if ( has_term( 'popular', 'song_category', $object_id ) ) 
        return;

    // Get the term ID of the popular term. We will get the term object by term slug. 
    $term_object = get_term_by( 'slug', 'popular', 'song_category' );
    $term_id     = $term_object->term_id;

    // Check if our post is going to be added as popular, if not, bail 
    if ( $term_id != $tt_id ) // Set the correct ID for popular term
        return;

    /**
     * We are now sure that our post is not yet popular, and we will be 
     * making it popular, so lets continue
     *
     * We will be sending a mail when the term is inserted. We will use the 
     * set_object_terms hook as it fires on successful insertion of the term 
     */
    add_action( 'set_object_terms', function ( $object_id )
    {
        $post    = get_post( $object_id );
        $author  = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
        $terms   = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'song_category' );
        $email   = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_email', true );
        $message = 'Hi ' . $author->display_name;

        wp_mail( $email, "Your song is now in the popular section!", $message );
    });
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi @Pieter-Goosen thank you kindly for the explanation and help.  I tried the following code and got PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':' .  My guess is the : should be a semi colon.   I changed it to a semi colon but doesn't seem to be working.   Nothing sends now.  I apoligize in advance if this is a silly question but do I need to pass in values for   $object_id, $tt_id ?

Comment: I put echo "test"; die(); in a few places to see if it gets triggered.  It works all the way up until this part >>>>  if ( 1 !== $tt_id ) .  If I put "test"; die(); below that part and add to popular nothing happens.

Comment: Also it seems to be working without if ( 1 !== $tt_id ) return; .   I am going to test around more.  Would love to hear your genius thoughts! :)

Comment: Hi I am not able to get this to work.  I am looking in the wp_term_taxonomy table in the database at the first column term_taxonomy_id.  I even tried term_id but that didn't work either.  The code gets to here and then bails 1 !== $tt_id .

Comment: Okay so been testing for a little and can't get it to work.  If I have no categorys selected and then select popular and press update and if I print the info before the " check if ( $term_id != $tt_id )  " I get the following out put >>>> print_r($term_id); is returning 94 and print_r($tt_id); is returning 99.  
If I take out if ( $term_id != $tt_id )  the function works.  The only caveot I found with taking it out was that if you add multiple categories AT ONCE it will do whatever code you put multiple times.   But if its in popular and you add new category nothing happens which is good.

Comment: My code work as expected on my local install. Everything executes after the term id check if I insert a specific term that is not yet assigned to the post. Are you sure that you do not have some kind of issue with a duplicate term. Getting `94` as `$term_id` and `99` as `$tt_id` is really really strange and should not happen. The issue is definitely not my code, so you should start by having a look at how your terms was inserted into db, and also make sure all values are as what you expect them to be

Comment: Just one request, can you please delete your previous comments to avoid this being auto flagged as a comment explosion ;-)